# FDT 5 fresh install Could not connect to the player

Tags: fdt

I am new to FDT and I would like to be able to move my project over to FDT when I figure out how to use it but I have just downloaded the latest version 5 today and followed instructions as provided on website but the result is.

[Info] Could not connect to the player, will try to connect for the next 72000 ms
[Info] Listening to port 7935.

[Info] Could not connect to the player, will try to connect for the next 64000 ms
[Info] Listening to port 7935.

[Info] Could not connect to the player, will try to connect for the next 56000 ms
[Info] Listening to port 7935.

....until

[Info] Could not connect to the player, debug session stopped. Maybe you do not have the Debug Flash Player installed.

I have searched all I can through google and attempted everything I could find but unfortunately no luck.

I am using win7/64 with latest most recent version of fdt 5 as of today with latest flash player debugger.  I am really not sure how to proceed at this point so I would appreciate advice from anyone else who is using version 5 and can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a 64 bit version of FDT 5, the external SWF-Viewer is part of FDT and therefor 64 bit instance as well. Under Windows it rely on the Flash Player Version that is installed for Internet Explorer. Unfortunately the Flash Debug Player is only available as a 32 bit version which cause that the external SWF Viewer is just a normal flash player instance to which FDT could obviously not connect to.
In order to debug your applications you have the following options:

- Use the standalone Flash Debug Player as launcher
- Use an external Browser. You can set up which browser to use in the Preferences > General > Web Browser
- When you use FDT 5.5: The team has implemented a solution for windows 64 bit users to launch the external swf viewer as an 32 bit instance so that it is able to utilize the flash debug player. Therefor you need to point FDT 5.5 to a 32 java installation under Preferences > FDT > Tools > Java 32. This option is only available to Windows 64 bit users.

Comment: Thank you for providing the options I tried the 5.5 beta and it works.

Answer (score 2):

or simply link your sdk to flash debugger player.

Preferences > FTD > Tools > Flash > Flash Player

point to your debugger player
in mac, something like this: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Players/Debug/Flash Player Debugger.app

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a MAC and are using Lion, also check that in preferences > energy saver, the automatically choose for best results option is un ticked as this caused issues in previous versions of FDT using adl to compile and display.

I also made this template in case this helps..

http://theboywhocriedwoolf.com/air-3-3-simulator-support-for-fdt-5-5/

Answer (score 0):

Please double [check](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html#main_Find_Flash_Player_version_type_and_capabilities__Flash_developers_only_) if you have the Debug Player.
If not, [grab a copy](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).
otherwise check if flashlog.txt exists on your machine.
Depending on your OS is should be in a similar location to this:

```
Windows 95/98/ME/2000/XP

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs

Windows Vista

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs

Macintosh OS X

/Users/username/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/Logs/

Linux

/home/username/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/
```

If the file is there, try to open it in a log viewer or even text editor that support updates to files and run a swf that makes `trace()` calls. You should see some output.
If that's fine, you should also be able to run files from FDT and see the traces in the console/output. My machine is slower and sometimes it takes a while for the connection to be made, especially when compiling a swf for the first time.

Still, if that doesn't work, have look at [this guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_04.html) and check if **mm.cfg** is properly configured with regards to **flashlog.txt/traces**.

Comment: Yes I have confirmed that I am using the debug player, the contents of mm.cfg is:

PolicyFileLog=1
PolicyFileLogAppend=1
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1

Trace() calls made from browser work perfectly fine in writing to the flashlog.txt file.

Unfortunately trace() calls from fdt do not result to any outputs at all which I still am not sure of as to why.

I am currently working inside of FlashDevelop so some previous configurations where done to get FlashDevelop up and running.

Comment: Ouch ! Is there any difference between using the External Viewer or the Standalone Flash Player ?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons FDT and Flash Develop don't connect to debugger. Just adding 2 more ways, i got it solved. I am assuming, the Flash Debug Player has been specified in FDT=>Preferences=>Flash . And Debug Configurations are pointing to Adobe Flash Player.

1) After when the debug flash player shows up, and the time, when fdt console starts showing the message

> Info] Could not connect to the player, will try to connect for the
>   next 64000 ms [Info] Listening to port 7935.

Just close the player. And locate the Debug Player manually through "Finder". Once the Debug Player is open, go to file menu, and locate the swf file. As soon as the file opens, the FDT should start showing "connected to debugger" message in the console window.

(2) If the above does not work,then here is the 2nd way, i followed:

Open the compiled swf, right click anywhere inside, and click "Debugger". This will open a dialog box everytime, the debugger opens.

Next time, the FDT starts debugging, it will open up a dialog box. Just click on "At IP address", and leave the input field blank. Click continue. That's all. This should solve the connection problem.

[image]